# jQuery validate plugin not working in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, jquery-validate

I am looking to implement jQuery validate plugin to validate my custom form in WordPress, but the validation isn't working and the form is submitted despite the errors.

Here's what I have done correctly :

1. jQuery has been called properly at the top.
2. The validate plugin is in the footer and called properly as well.
3. The HTML form elements are all okay and I have triple checked all my 'name' values.

The validate script is where I think the problem lies :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('#wpcf7_298').validate({
            rules: {
                wordsno: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true
                },

                dynamictext-419: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },

                select-box: {
                    required: true,

                }
            },

            messages: {
                wordsno: "Please fill the field",
                dynamictext-419: "Please enter a valid email address.",
                select-box: "Please choose your order type."
            }
        })          

        $('#sbbutton').click(function() {
        $("#wpcf7_298").valid();});

        });

</script>
```

Comment: any error in the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `key`s to the validate method are wrong

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#wpcf7_298').validate({
        rules: {
            wordsno: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },

            'dynamictext-419': {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },

            'select-box': {
                required: true,

            }
        },

        messages: {
            wordsno: "Please fill the field",
            'dynamictext-419': "Please enter a valid email address.",
            'select-box': "Please choose your order type."
        }
    })
```

In a object, keys with non alpha numerical values like `-` has to be enclosed within single/double quotes.